# Force a group of tests to run sequentially

Tags: c#, .net, integration-testing, visual-studio-2019

I'm writing integration tests in Visual Studio 2019 for a c# network library. Because the library requires access to a specific port, the tests can only be run sequentially, including `Prepare()` and `Cleanup()` methods.

Is there a way to force a group of test classes (the group of integration tests) to run sequentially?

I've only been able to add these tests to my test project as **unit tests** as I see no other options when creating new test projects or adding tests.  Do I need to adopt a different test framework to accomplish this?

The format of my integration test classes is generally:

```
[TestClass]
public class IntegrationTests_TestClass01
{
    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void Prepare(TestContext context)
    {
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void IntegrationTests_TestMethod01()
    {
    }

    [ClassCleanup]
    public static void Cleanup()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate.  I need the entire test class to run sequentially, as `Prepare()` and `Cleanup()` differ between integration tests.  Each class will have a number of testable scenarios.